# What should I do with mongodb security installed in aws ec2?

Tags: mongodb, aws

I using aws linux freetier

When I entered my site today, mongodb all collection was drop... OTL

(I checked the global log and confirmed that the Chinese ip dropped...)

When I installed mongodb, my /etc/mongod.conf setting

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: change my port num
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

next i was aws security group open and write my port num and anywhere setting

Is this a problem? What should I add more? 
Please teach me

Comment: After enabling authorization, did you create the super user? (and then other users)

Comment: The [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) in the manual provides a list of security measures you can take.

Comment: yes! i made adminuser and dbuser @@JJussi

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few things to read up upon:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/

In your mongo.conf its good to disable the REST API and http interface.

Use a non default Mongo port e.g not 27017 and use AWS security groups to only allow that port to a given IP not to the world.

Comment: hi @ollieB 
I'm sorry, can you please explain it more easily? i don't know mongo,conf rest api and http interface and port ip(mean my ip? or anywhere?) but i'm not use 27017

Comment: FYI, the REST API and HTTP interfaces are disabled by default in MongoDB 2.6+ and deprecated since MongoDB 3.2. Definitely recommended not to enable either of these options (especially for a production deployment).

Comment: I agree but I have seen people in the past with little knowledge of Mongo enable things such as the HTTP interface because it looks nice.

Comment: Also please can you link me to a piece of literature which that states that the REST API is deprecated?

Comment: @OllieB REST/HTTP interface deprecation is mentioned in the MongoDB manual, including the [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#run-mongodb-with-secure-configuration-options) you suggested. For more information see [MongoDB Configuration Hardening](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/). These interfaces should never be enabled on a production deployment (or really, any deployment). There are more secure (and feature rich) admin UIs available for RESTful interaction and monitoring.